# SEC EDGAR 13F source HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parsing, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403

Please help, SEC EDGAR used to work flawlessly until now. it gives HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1541617/000110465920125814/xslForm13F_X01/infotable.xml")
df=tables[3] 
df
```

Comment: There's only one table on that page; is that the correct url in the question?

Comment: no? there are 3 at least one-header, next in the right corner, and the last that I need

Comment: My guess would be it is identifying you as a bot and blocking you. Might need to use different techniques to access the page to mimic a human (use headers, selenium, etc). Also, there are 4 tables on this page and if you are looking for the main chunk of data, it is actually in table[4] now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the site is rejecting your request since it detects the request is automated. You can bypass this if you add the header `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0` to the http request since that will make it look like the request is coming from a firefox browser. Unfortunately though, pd.read_html does not support changing the request headers, so we have to make the request on our own using the requests library.

Install requests with `pip install requests`

Then change your code to look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Makes a request to the url
request = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1541617/000110465920125814/xslForm13F_X01/infotable.xml", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

# Pass the html response into read_html
tables = pd.read_html(request.text)

df = tables[3] 
print(df)
```

One thing I have noticed about the site is it will not allow requests from non-residential ip addresses and will always give you a 403. So if you are executing this code somewhere in the cloud (such as repl.it, through a vpn, or similar) this code will not work at all. Running it on my home computer this code works perfectly though. The site also says that it will block your ip address if you make more then 10 requests per second or a excess amount of requests overall, so do be sure to tread lightly on how many times you make requests to the website.

Comment: Dear Themis, thank you so much for the elaborated answer, you are a genius, everything works!

Comment: @IgBell I'm really happy that helped you out and everything works in your project now! Thank you for the kind words as well, I'm very flattered. I wish you a good rest of your day!

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that simply adding a user-agent would fix this error.

[However now it seems that user-agent has to be in a specific format](https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data)

> User-Agent: Sample Company Name AdminContact@.com

So rather than using a real user-agent (eg from your browser), was able to get it working using:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Company info@company.com)
```