# Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection - Webscraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I'm trying to run a script that collects several fields of information on the SEC Edgar website.  Here is an example of a url on the website: "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001089892/000156821423000002/0001568214-23-000002.txt"

```
getRawValue <- function(parentTag, rawText){
  res <- c()
  indices <- gregexpr(parentTag, rawText)[[1]] # Take indices of every tag occurance
  for( i in 1:length(indices)){
    if(i %% 2 == 1){
      substr <- substr(rawText, indices[i], indices[i+1])
      val <- rm_between(substr, "<value>", "</value>", extract=TRUE)
      res <- c(res, val)
    }
  }
  return(res)
```

}

I'm receiving the following error when I run the try catch process that works through the list of URLs: Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 403

Comment: See some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368856/sec-edgar-13f-source-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73482071/web-scraping-sec-site-but-i-am-receiving-http-error-403-forbidden. It looks like the website uses techniques to prevent scraping. They are probably detecting too many requests from your IP address and are blocking the request.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the SEC requires you to declare a user agent or it gives you a rate-limit page. If you check the content of the response you're currently getting, it'll mention the rate-limiting and how to get around it:

```r
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001089892/000156821423000002/0001568214-23-000002.txt" |>
  httr::GET() |>
  httr::content() |>
  xml2::xml_find_all("//p")
```

returns

```
{xml_nodeset (11)}
 [1] <p>To allow for equitable access to all users, SEC reserves the right to limit requests originating from u ...
 [2] <p>Please declare your traffic by updating your user agent to include company specific information.</p>
 [3] <p>For best practices on efficiently downloading information from SEC.gov, including the latest EDGAR fili ...
 [4] <p>For more information, please see the SEC’s <a href="#internet">Web Site Privacy and Security Policy</a> ...
 [5] <p>Reference ID: 0.e4d0df17.1676410606.24fa6186</p>
 [6] <p>By using this site, you are agreeing to security monitoring and auditing. For security purposes, and to ...
 [7] <p>Unauthorized attempts to upload information and/or change information on any portion of this site are s ...
 [8] <p>To ensure our website performs well for all users, the SEC monitors the frequency of requests for SEC.g ...
 [9] <p>If a user or application submits more than 10 requests per second, further requests from the IP address ...
[10] <p>Note that this policy may change as the SEC manages SEC.gov to ensure that the website performs efficie ...
[11] <p class="note"><b>Note:</b> We do not offer technical support for developing or debugging scripted downlo ...
```

so if you declare the user agent (I'm using the default of "httr" here, but you should declare who you are otherwise if you're doing this repeatedly to make sure you don't run into someone else using httr's default values):

```r
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001089892/000156821423000002/0001568214-23-000002.txt" |>
  GET(user_agent(agent="httr"))
```

you'll get a code of 200 and the actual XML page as content:

```
Response [https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1089892/000156821423000002/0001568214-23-000002.txt]
  Date: 2023-02-14 21:39
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Size: 5.11 kB
<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001568214-23-000002.txt : 20230213
<SEC-HEADER>0001568214-23-000002.hdr.sgml : 20230213
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20230213141446
ACCESSION NUMBER:       0001568214-23-000002
CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:  4
PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:      1
CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT: 20230213
FILED AS OF DATE:       20230213
DATE AS OF CHANGE:      20230213
```

As mentioned in the other SO questions from the comments on your question, do tread lightly with this in a loop because the user agent will get blocked if you request more than 10 pages per second, so a `Sys.sleep(0.1)` will help in the loop too.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  How would you put in the user agent?  The package in R that gives me the list of filings also requires an agent, which can just be my email address.  I'm just wondering syntactically how to include it in this script.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The speed of querying isn't that essential.  I'm trying to formulate the syntax with the user_agent in it

Comment: @js80 What package is this? The code you've shared doesn't actually do any downloading or HTTP requests at all - it looks like a parser for the content. If you edit your question to include a reproducible example (or even the actual request code) I can help you edit the request.

Comment: The first step in the script is querying the "edgar" package to getDailyMaster.  The script then goes to the actual forms that were filed to collect some fields of data that are missing in the getDailyMaster call.

Comment: @js80 Please edit your question to include a reproducible example. I don't know what querying a package means or what these actual forms are, so I can't reconstruct your request or tell you where to add `user_agent()`.

Comment: I created the modified URL with the user_agent but I'm still getting the error.